# Is there a way for publishing an Android App with API level 26 from UNITY 5.6.6?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-api, google-console-developer

I made an AR app using **UNITY 5.6.6** and I'm trying to publish my app to Google Play that need ***at least API Level 26***. I have tried different ways to achieve that targeted level of API but achieved nothing and the Google Console only recognize my app'S API as *level 22*. Yes, it can be done easily if I use Unity earlier version (I am using Unity 2018 for my other published Apps), but I have to use this particular version because I'm using a little old plugin that only can be stable using those early versions of UNITY.

**Here above some ways I've tried on Unity 5.6.6 :**

1. I have tried using SDK tools version **26.1**
2. I have tried using SDK tools version **r25.2.5**
   [sdkmanager](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1361x6hnzM5Abz-x9rVq64TVrx7ESvmI8/preview)
3. Here is my configuration I've tried on **Build Settings-Other Settings**
   [config 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PilmJkDKI2g37UgH7iCcrs3wAz8l56si/preview)
   [config 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PilmJkDKI2g37UgH7iCcrs3wAz8l56si/preview)

Here is the message I received from Google Console
[google console message](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hZa1Q-GmVNjwjmHNkMw9RN3c4xxy-O3T/preview)

I hope someone have experienced this and solved the problem. I appreciate your time and help alot! Thank you!

Comment: I doubt it. Unity likely doesn't know what those APIs look like, as API 26 came out after Unity 5.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

it seems unity 5.6 only goes up to api minimum of  25 (android 7.1)

api level 26 was released march of 2017 and unity 2017 was released in February 2017 for comparison

so unity 5.6 was done being updated before the release of api level 26

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. If you set the Target API to "Automatic (highest installed)", Unity will use the highest version of the Android SDK that it detects on your system. For example, when I build using that setting in Unity 5.6, it uses API Level 28, since that is the highest version of the Android SDK that I have installed on my machine.